# Xlib.h and Xutil.h not found in Eclipse, how can I fix this?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, xlib

I'm a newbie to Eclipse IDE for C/C++ development. I just installed MingW and set it up as my system's environment variable. I am trying to make an application that uses the X library but eclipse cant seem to find it. Eclipse works with any other simple standard library functions but it cant find the X library. Please Help!

Here's a sample code snippet that's failing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h> // Can't find this
#include <X11/Xutil.h> // Or this...

int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Do I have to download the X library from somewhere? If so then from where and where do I paste it to? Please tell me what to do in order for me to start coding using the Xlib in Eclipse. If you find any useful links, please dont hesitate to post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download and build the [X.org libraries](http://www.x.org/wiki/) with MinGW in order to successfully build any X client. Look under `current/src/lib/` on any download mirror.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand what you mean? Which files must I download from the following link: ftp://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/x.org/current/src/lib/
And where do I extract them to? Can you explain in detail? Thanks.

Comment: I can't explain in detail, because I don't know the details; writing X clients that run under Windows is something almost no one does. Certainly I have never done so.